# Is this a FIR algorithm?

Tags: finite-impulse-response

I'm kind of out of my element here trying to understand this algorithm and I wanted to see if this is a FIR algorithm or not? If this isn't the right place to ask this, can someone point me to a place?

The reason I ask is because this code is not well commented and not defined anywhere and I'm relatively new to this problem domain.

```
' Called BY CAntennaT with ref to a one-dim array of single's
'
Public Function Filter3_Ant(data As Variant, ByVal CNo As Integer, ByVal times As Integer) As Integer
Dim i As Integer, k As Integer
Dim Anz As Integer
Dim I_1 As Variant      ' value at I-1
Dim I_0 As Variant      ' saved value at I-0

    If times <= 0 Then Exit Function

    ' use filter3 only where it makes sense
    If (Module.GetTestFlag(CNo) And (SIMPLE_GAIN + SDARS_STD)) = 0 Then Exit Function

    Anz = VUbound(data)
    If Anz < 3 Then Exit Function

    Do
        I_1 = data(1)  ' preset with I+2, then first becomes 0.5 * F(I) + 0.5 * F(I+1)
        For i = 0 To Anz - 2
            I_0 = data(i)
            data(i) = I_1 * 0.25 + data(i) * 0.5 + data(i + 1) * 0.25
            I_1 = I_0
        Next
        data(i) = I_1 * 0.5 + data(i) * 0.5

        times = times - 1
    Loop While times > 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be an awkwardly-written implementation of an FIR filter with impulse response:

$$
h[n] = [0.25, 0.5, 0.25]
$$

except for the boundary condition at the endpoints, where the output samples on the edges are just the average of the corresponding input sample and the one next to it.

Comment: How do you think one would come to the conclusion to make those the impulse responses? I was under the impression that the impulse response coefficients were based on the number of terms in the series.

Comment: `data(i) = I_1 * 0.25 + data(i) * 0.5 + data(i + 1) * 0.25`